# Libreoffice private tmp folder

Tags: libreoffice

I am running a very common scenario in my opinion. I run Firefox on Ubuntu 18.04, choose to open a LibreOffice document (instead of downloading it) but I get this error:

```
 /tmp/mozilla_cip1/***.odt does not exist.
```

The file is there though. What's more, if I do a 
`touch /tmp/a.txt` , LibreOffice still cannot see it. So I am guessing that LibreOffice has his own private folder. ( I installed it from Snap if that makes a difference).

Could somebody give me a hint on how to solve it ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. Probably you installed it via Ubuntu software.
You should remove the snap version and use the following command

```
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

Comment: So weird. Any idea as to what caused this problem with the snap package?

Comment: Also on the same page. Unfortunately couldn't figure out what the issue with the snap version is.

Comment: My best guess is that snaps don't have access to the tmp folder, and LibreOffice wrongly reports that the file does not exist.

Comment: Here is the corresponding bug report: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1790608